# Finding repeating group of values

Tags: r, stata

I have the below dataset which I want to figure out all *unique groups* consisting of 2 or more *pids* that repeat across **org** *and/or* **overtime**.
So the desired outcome would be to identify the group comprising pid 11, 23 and 9 that appears across 2 org a & c and over the year 2017 & 2018. Note that I only need the group of pids to appear either across org or over year. No need both criteria to be satisfied simultaneously..

At the moment, I am more interested in repeating groups of pids across **org**

Your help to address this issue either in R or Stata would be greatly appreciated!

| year | org | pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | a | 11 |
| 2017 | a | 23 |
| 2017 | a | 9 |
| 2017 | a | 1 |
| 2017 | b | 4 |
| 2017 | b | 5 |
| 2017 | c | 11 |
| 2017 | c | 9 |
| 2017 | c | 23 |
| 2018 | a | 11 |
| 2018 | a | 23 |
| 2018 | a | 9 |
| 2018 | a | 1 |
| 2018 | b | 4 |
| 2018 | b | 5 |
| 2018 | b | 8 |
| 2018 | c | 11 |
| 2018 | c | 9 |
| 2018 | c | 23 |

Answer (score 0):

To select `pid` that occur in more than one `org` **or** `year` you can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(pid) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(org) > 1 || n_distinct(year) > 1) %>%
  ungroup

#    year org     pid
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1  2017 a         1
# 2  2018 a         1
# 3  2017 b         4
# 4  2018 b         4
# 5  2017 b         5
# 6  2018 b         5
# 7  2017 a         9
# 8  2017 c         9
# 9  2018 a         9
#10  2018 c         9
#11  2017 a        11
#12  2017 c        11
#13  2018 a        11
#14  2018 c        11
#15  2017 a        23
#16  2017 c        23
#17  2018 a        23
#18  2018 c        23
```

To select `pid` that occur in more than one `org` **and** `year` you can use :

```
df %>%
  arrange(pid) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(org) > 1 && n_distinct(year) > 1) %>%
  ungroup

#    year org     pid
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1  2017 a         9
# 2  2017 c         9
# 3  2018 a         9
# 4  2018 c         9
# 5  2017 a        11
# 6  2017 c        11
# 7  2018 a        11
# 8  2018 c        11
# 9  2017 a        23
#10  2017 c        23
#11  2018 a        23
#12  2018 c        23
```

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks so much for your prompt response. I can identify repeating PID if it is a single PID. However, my goal was to identify a GROUP of 2 or more PIDs who always go together. Hence these groups can be found more than once either across org or year. In essense, I want to identify cliques but not using the cliques function in R because that function gives me results with many groups/cliques which NEVER repeat across different org or year

Comment: @ThiBui How will your final expected output look?

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Ideally I want to create a new column called clique which identify a group comprising 2 or more PIDs that appear in more than 1 org like below
| year | org | pid | clique 
| ---- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | a | 11 | 11,23,9 |
| 2017 | a | 23 | 11,23,9 |
| 2017 | a | 9 | 11,23,9 |
| 2017 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2017 | b | 4 | 4 |
| 2017 | b | 5 | 5 |
| 2017 | c | 11 | 11,23,9 |
| 2017 | c | 9 |  11,23,9 |
| 2017 | c | 23 | 11,23,9 |

Comment: @ThiBui Output is not clear in comments. Can you edit your post to include that?

Comment: Or if impossible, at least a binary variable | year | org | pid | clique 
| ---- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | a | 11 | 1 |
| 2017 | a | 23 | 1 |
| 2017 | a | 9 | 1 |
| 2017 | a | 1 | 0 |
| 2017 | b | 4 | 0 |
| 2017 | b | 5 | 0 |
| 2017 | c | 11 | 1 |
| 2017 | c | 9 |  1 |
| 2017 | c | 23 | 1 |